# What are the elements of evidence of willful failure?

Tags: florida

Assume that a Florida Condominium (Defendant) has a duty to provide access to records under [per governing law FS718.111(12)c](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2002/Chapter718/All):

(c)  The official records of the association are open to inspection by any association member or the authorized representative of such member at all reasonable times. The right to inspect the records includes the right to make or obtain copies, at the reasonable expense, if any, of the association member. The association may adopt reasonable rules regarding the frequency, time, location, notice, and manner of record inspections and copying. The failure of an association to provide the records within 10 working days after receipt of a written request shall create a rebuttable presumption that the association willfully failed to comply with this paragraph. A unit owner who is denied access to official records is entitled to the actual damages or minimum damages for the association's **willful failure to comply with this paragraph**. The minimum damages shall be $50 per calendar day up to 10 days, the calculation to begin on the 11th working day after receipt of the written request. The failure to permit inspection of the association records as provided herein entitles any person prevailing in an enforcement action to recover reasonable attorney's fees from the person in control of the records who, directly or indirectly, knowingly denied access to the records for inspection. The association shall maintain an adequate number of copies of the declaration, articles of incorporation, bylaws, and rules, and all amendments to each of the foregoing, as well as the question and answer sheet provided for in s. 718.504 and year-end financial information required in this section on the condominium property to ensure their availability to unit owners and prospective purchasers, and may charge its actual costs for preparing and furnishing these documents to those requesting the same

Assume:

- A petitioner requested in writing: for access to all Association records (comprising paper records, which are not electronic) and request a specific date to provide physical access.
- The Association fails to provide physical access to records within 30 days of a request.
- All communications are performed in writing / email, which establish evidence and a timeline

What are the elements of evidence required to show "willful failure to comply" with said statute?

Comment: Isn't it answered in the statute?  All you have to show is that they didn't provide the documents within 10 days.  Then the burden of proof shifts to them to show that it was not willful.

Answer (score 1):

Q:  What are the elements of evidence required to show "willful failure to comply" with said statute?

A:  The failure of an association to provide the records within 10 working days after receipt of a written request shall create a rebuttable presumption that the association willfully failed to comply with this paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

[§718.501](https://www.flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2002/Chapter718/All) may help. Para (1)(d)4 says that

> The division may impose a civil penalty against a developer or
> association, or its assignee or agent, for any violation of this
> chapter or a rule promulgated pursuant hereto. The division may impose
> a civil penalty individually against any officer or board member who
> willfully and knowingly violates a provision of this chapter, a rule
> adopted pursuant hereto, or a final order of the division. *The term
> "willfully and knowingly" means that the division informed the officer
> or board member that his or her action or intended action violates
> this chapter, a rule adopted under this chapter, or a final order of
> the division and that the officer or board member refused to comply
> with the requirements of this chapter, a rule adopted under this
> chapter, or a final order of the division*.

Notice the subtle distinction between "willful failure to comply" in the section that you cite, and the above which applies to the whole chapter which defines "willfully and knowingly". And it is clearly a specially-defined term specific to this chapter, since that is not the ordinary meaning of "willfully and knowingly". So the elements of that failure are that the division notified someone of a violation, and that they refused to comply.

Where it says "A unit owner who is denied access to official records is entitled to the actual damages or minimum damages for the association's willful failure to comply with this paragraph", the condition under which a unit owner is entitled to damages is the fact of being denied access to official records. You may be thinking that the right of action is limited to cases where an illegal denial of access to official records is "when it is willful". Later in the paragraph, it says that you are entitled to damages "from the person in control of the records who, directly or indirectly, knowingly denied access to the records for inspection". You can put these two together to conclude that damages are due from a person who "willfully and knowingly" fails to comply.

There are two ways you can determine that you have been denied access to records. One is that 10 working days have passed since you made the request, and they have not complied. The other is that they tell you "we deny your request".